# haskell-stack store-0.3: libz.so

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When building `haskell-stack` from I get the following error:

```
store-0.3: download
store-0.3: configure
store-0.3: build

--  While building package store-0.3 using:
      /tmp/haskell-stack-20170403-52407-1rpyzwy/stack-1.4.0/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.22.5.0_ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /tmp/haskell-stack-20170403-52407-1rpyzwy/stack-1.4.0/.stack-work/logs/store-0.3.log

    Configuring store-0.3...
    Building store-0.3...
    Preprocessing library store-0.3...
    [ 1 of 11] Compiling Data.Store.Streaming.Internal ( src/Data/Store/Streaming/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/Store/Streaming/Internal.o )
    [ 2 of 11] Compiling System.IO.ByteBuffer ( src/System/IO/ByteBuffer.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/System/IO/ByteBuffer.o )
    [ 3 of 11] Compiling Data.Store.Impl  ( src/Data/Store/Impl.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/Store/Impl.o )
    [ 4 of 11] Compiling Data.Store.TH    ( src/Data/Store/TH.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/Store/TH.o )
    [ 5 of 11] Compiling Data.Store.TH.Internal ( src/Data/Store/TH/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/Store/TH/Internal.o )
    [ 6 of 11] Compiling Data.Store.Internal ( src/Data/Store/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/Store/Internal.o )
    <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libz.so (libz.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I have `zlib` development installed on my machine.

Comment: That's strange!  libz is used by the zlib package, which is a dependency of the streaming-commons package.  So I would have expected this issue to crop up while compiling the zlib package, rather than when compiling store.  If you do "stack exec -- ghc-pkg unregister zlib" and try building again, what happens?

Comment: Do you have the systems libz-dev package installed?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed to add the two flags to specify zlib include and lib:

```
--extra-include-dirs
--extra-lib-dirs
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `libz-dev` package installation solved it.

```
sudo apt install libz-dev
```